# Otimizar cálculo do fatorial utilizando vetor

Tags: c

Enunciado da questão:

> Ler uma matriz A do tipo vetor com 5 elementos numéricos inteiros.
>   Construir uma matriz B de mesmo tipo, sendo cada elemento da matriz B a fatorial do elemento correspondente da matriz A.
>   Apresentar os elementos da matriz B.

Consegui fazer, mas queria saber como melhorar meu algoritmo.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   int vet[5], i, fat, fat2, fat3, fat4, fat5;
   for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
   {
     printf("Digite um numero :\n");
     scanf("%d", &vet[i]);
   }
   for(fat = 1; vet[0] > 1; vet[0] = vet[0] - 1)
   {
     fat *= vet[0];
   }
   for(fat2 = 1; vet[1] > 1; vet[1] = vet[1] - 1)
   {
      fat2 *= vet[1];
   }
   for(fat3 = 1; vet[2] > 1; vet[2] = vet[2] - 1)
   {
     fat3 *= vet[2];
   }
   for(fat4 = 1; vet[3] > 1; vet[3] = vet[3] - 1)
   {
     fat4 *= vet[3];
   }
   for(fat5 = 1; vet[4] > 1; vet[4] = vet[4] - 1)
   {
     fat5 *= vet[4];
   }
     printf("%d\n", fat);
     printf("%d\n", fat2);
     printf("%d\n", fat3);
     printf("%d\n", fat4);
     printf("%d\n", fat5);
  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isso se resolve facilmente colocando um `for` dentro do outro:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int vet[5], fat[5], i;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("Digite um numero:\n");
        scanf("%d", &vet[i]);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (fat[i] = 1; vet[i] > 1; vet[i]--) {
            fat[i] *= vet[i];
        }
        printf("%d\n", fat[i]);
    }
    //system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Também troquei o `vet[i] = vet[i] - 1` por `vet[i]--`.

Testando com essa entrada:

```
5
12
4
7
3
```

É produzida essa saída:

```
120
479001600
24
5040
6
```

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/3ku3Uv)

Comment: Muito obrigado,já marquei com certa a resposta

Comment: @rafaelmarques Obrigado. ;)